# Docker : How can I save my database in a container, and use it in another container?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm new on docker and I use an image of Cassandra. But I have a problem : when I create a database on cassandra and save it on a second image, I would like to find it when I use another container... Problem : The second image is bigger than the first one (means that it detect the changes) but I can't find my database neither my keyspace... Any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to create a data volume. This will mean that you will have your two original images and a third one, which will be used for the sole purpose of containerizing your data.

There is an excellent reference here that deals with your options https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes

The documentation at the link explains how to link your newly created volume with your existing images.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd ! I'll try and give you a feedback later in the day !

Comment: Hi ryn-mgni, Hope that helps :-)